# Remove XML format from auto-generated help in WCF 4 REST service

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I'm using WCF 4 and WCF REST C# templates to build out an API using JSON as the transport mechanism.

From the web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see, I've disabled the automaticFormatSelection and specified the default format as JSON.

However, when the help files get generated they include both XML and JSON formats in the endpoint method examples:

(I can't upload a picture to StackOverflow yet sadly... so here's a snippet)

```
Url: https://awesome.myapi.com/1.0/account/

HTTP Method: POST

Message direction       Format      Body
Request               Xml         Example,Schema
Request               Json        Example
Response                 Xml         Example,Schema
Response                 Json        Example
```

So the question: Is it possible to have the auto-generated help not include XML?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I'm having the same issue, although there is now way for the user to get an XML response from the endpoint, the help page still shows it.

Comment: Hi Omar, sadly no, I've not found a way to get around this.  I'm hoping the HTTP Web API from the WCF team will be able to inspect the formats actually being sent.